# Animate movement of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to animate the entire movement of my search box. So far the opacity and width animate, but once the width is set to 0 and the animation is complete, the area where the search box collapses does so with no animation. Instead what I want is that the width affects the positioning of other elements dynamically.

[Non Dynamic Resizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAcmb.gif)

My javascript apppends .show to the search box

```
input.search-box {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0px;
    transition: 1s;
}

input.search-box.show {
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 1s;
}
```

There's also another problem of there being blank space where there shouldn't be, between the search icon and the home icon. I'm pretty sure its because of the search box.

```
<li>
  <a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
</li>
<li class="search-box-list">
  <input id="search-box" type="text" class="search-box special" placeholder="Input STEAMID..." />
</li>
<li class="search-icon-list">
  <a href="#" class="fa fa-search search-icon"></a>
</li>
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: The blank space is most probably from the LI container. Use inspect element. Should be no questions after you inspect it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `width: 100%` use a fixed width:

```
width: 200px;
```

***Edit:*** or as noted by @nine you can use `vw` unit as-well!

Example:

```js
$(".search-toggle").on("click", function(){
  $(".search-box").toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
ul{
  text-align: right;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
input.search-box {
  position:relative;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0px;
  transition: 1s;
}
input.search-box.show {
  width: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input class="search-box" type="search" placeholder="input STEAMID...">
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="search-toggle" href="javascript:;"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(P.S: the blank space is most probably caused by a parent padding...)

Comment: While this answered my question, setting it to a set px width is not good for when the user has a smaller (or larger) browser. A better way would be to use viewport widths. Which worked just as well and worked on all size browsers.

Comment: @nine great found!